# C++ run two functions(threads) in turn infinitely

Tags: c++, multithreading, stack-overflow, daemon

I want to create a daemon on Linux that basically will be running two functions one after another(both voids). I tried two approaches:

1) First

```
void func1()
{
    boost::posix_time::seconds workTime(3);
    boost::this_thread::sleep(workTime);
    func2();
}
void func2()
{
    boost::posix_time::seconds workTime(3);
    boost::this_thread::sleep(workTime);
    func1();
}
int main()
{
    func1();
    return 0;
}
```

2) Second approach using threads:

```
void func1()
{
    boost::posix_time::seconds workTime(3);
    boost::this_thread::sleep(workTime);
    boost::thread func2thread(func2);
    func2thread.join();
}
void func2()
{
    boost::posix_time::seconds workTime(3);
    boost::this_thread::sleep(workTime);
    boost::thread func1thread(func1);
    func1thread.join();
}
int main()
{
    boost::thread func1thread(func1);
    func1thread.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Both cases will eventually cause stack overflow. The reason I want functions to run in turn is because I want the first one to populate an array, and the second one to process the values in it and then clear it. What is the best way to implement such a thing?

Comment: If they never run at the same time, why are they separate threads?

Comment: If you want some bit of logic to be run indefinitely, it has to be in a loop. If you try to do it recursively, you will eventually overflow the call stack.

Comment: `while (true) { func1(); func2(); }`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while (true) {
    func1();
    boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::seconds(3));
    func2();
    boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::seconds(3));
}
```

Would be the simplest thing that comes to mind

Comment: in c++11 you don't need boost for that

Comment: @Axalo Sure. That's not relevant to the question though, so I kept things as it is :)

Comment: I got trapped, I need to eat and get some sleep, thank you ))